How to center a stamp image in PYPDF2
I am working on a PDF tool website and adding an option to stamp all pages. For the backend I am using Flask.
This is the route code handling the stamp functionality:
@app.route('/stamp', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def add_stamp():
    try:
        content_file = request.files.get('contentFile')
        image_file = request.files.get('imageFile')

        if content_file and image_file:
            print('Content File:', content_file.filename)
            print('Image File:', image_file.filename)
        else:
            print('Files not received correctly')
            return jsonify({"error": "Files not received correctly"}), 400
        
        imagereader = PdfReader(image_file.stream)
        image_page = imagereader.pages[0]

        writer = PdfWriter()

        content_reader = PdfReader(content_file.stream)

        page_indices = list(range(0, len(content_reader.pages)))

        for index in page_indices:
            content_page = content_reader.pages[index]
            mediabox = content_page.mediabox
            content_page.merge_page(image_page)
            content_page.mediabox = mediabox
            writer.add_page(content_page)
        
        stamp_output = io.BytesIO()
        writer.write(stamp_output)
        stamp_output.seek(0)

        @after_this_request
        def cleanup(response):
            stamp_output.close()
            return response

        response = jsonify({
            'stamp': stamp_output.getvalue().decode('latin1'),
        })
        response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/octet-stream'
        return response
        

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
        return jsonify({"error": "Internal Server Error"}), 500

Using this code, I am able to add a stamp to the pages of the PDF file, but the stamp appears in the bottom left corner. I want the stamp to appear in the center of the PDF.
I tried using ChatGPT to solve this purpose, but had no luck there.
@app.route('/stamp', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin()
def add_stamp():
    try:
        content_file = request.files.get('contentFile')
        image_file = request.files.get('imageFile')

        if content_file and image_file:
            print('Content File:', content_file.filename)
            print('Image File:', image_file.filename)
        else:
            print('Files not received correctly')
            return jsonify({"error": "Files not received correctly"}), 400
        
        imagereader = PdfReader(image_file.stream)
        image_page = imagereader.pages[0]

        writer = PdfWriter()

        content_reader = PdfReader(content_file.stream)

        for content_page in content_reader.pages:
            content_mediabox = content_page.mediabox
            content_width = content_mediabox.width
            content_height = content_mediabox.height

            image_mediabox = image_page.mediabox
            image_width = image_mediabox.width
            image_height = image_mediabox.height

            # Calculate the center position
            center_x = (content_width - image_width) / 2
            center_y = (content_height - image_height) / 2

            # Translate the image page to the center position
            image_page.mediabox = RectangleObject([
                center_x, center_y,
                center_x + image_width, center_y + image_height
            ])

            content_page.merge_page(image_page)
            content_page.mediabox = content_mediabox  # Restore the original mediabox
            writer.add_page(content_page)
        
        stamp_output = io.BytesIO()
        writer.write(stamp_output)
        stamp_output.seek(0)

This is the code, given by ChatGPT, but this code in response, is giving an initial PDF with no stamp added.
My original code is adding a stamp, but at the bottom left corner, I just want that on every page the stamp should appear in the center.

I have simplified your code a bit to eliminate the need of the web framework, but it should be easy enough to integrate this into your code again:
from pypdf import PdfReader, PdfWriter, Transformation


# Work on the writer directly.
writer = PdfWriter(clone_from="input.pdf")
stamp = PdfReader("stamp.pdf").pages[0]

for page in writer.pages:
    content_mediabox = page.mediabox
    content_width = content_mediabox.width
    content_height = content_mediabox.height

    image_mediabox = stamp.mediabox
    image_width = image_mediabox.width
    image_height = image_mediabox.height

    # Calculate the center position
    center_x = (content_width - image_width) / 2
    center_y = (content_height - image_height) / 2

    # Generate the center transformation.
    transformation = Transformation().translate(tx=center_x, ty=center_y)

    # Add the stamp while using the transformation.
    page.merge_transformed_page(stamp, transformation)

writer.write("output.pdf")

